# How to create an object with constructor using hql query?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have two tables in database (CAR_BODY and MOTOR). I am writing hql query request. I need to get 3 columns from this table and create DTO-object.

Tables:
CAR_BODY        |
----------------|
ID              |
WEIGHT          |
NUMBER_OF_DOORS |
SPARE_WHEEL     |

| MOTOR |
| --- |
| ID |
| ENGINE_DISPLACEMENT |
| TORQUE |
| NUMBER_OF_CYLINDERS |

DTO-object:

```
public class CarInf{
        private float weight;
        private float engineDisplacement;
        private float torque;

        public CarInf(float weight, float engineDisplacement, float torque) {
            this.weight = weight;
            this.engineDisplacement = engineDisplacement;
            this.torque = torque;
        }

        public float getWeight() {
            return weight;
        }

        public void setWeight(float weight) {
            this.weight = weight;
        }

        public float getEngineDisplacement() {
            return engineDisplacement;
        }

        public void setEngineDisplacement(float engineDisplacement) {
            this.engineDisplacement = engineDisplacement;
        }

        public float getTorque() {
            return torque;
        }

        public void setTorque(float torque) {
            this.torque = torque;
        }
    }
```

This is my method in repository interface:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true,  value = "select new CarInf(cb.weight, m.engineDisplacement, m.torque) from Motor as m join CarBody as cb on m.id = cb.id where m.id = ?1")
    public List<CarInf> getCarInf(Long id);
```

But I get org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet.

What's my mistake?

Comment: When you use `nativeQuery = true` your query become true-SQL. HQL is not nativeQuery.

Comment: Also change `?1` with `:id`.

Answer (score 0):

```
            String hql = "select s.svamAccNo, s.svamBrh, s.svamCustCode, l.lfcuTit1, l.lfcuSur1, l.lfcuOth1, s.svamAtmcdInName, s.svamAtmcdMothersMname "
                + " from Svam s, Lfcu l, Svp sv "
                + " where s.svamCustCode = l.lfcuCode "
                + " and s.svamProd = sv.id.svpsProd "
                + " and s.svamSubProd = sv.id.svpsSubProd "
                + " and s.svamAccNo = :p_acc_no ";

        Query query = em.createQuery(hql);
        query.setParameter("p_acc_no", kixcCustomerDetailsRequestDto.getAccountNo());
        query.setParameter("p_branch", kixcCustomerDetailsRequestDto.getBranch());
        

        List<Object[]> resultList = query.getResultList();

        Object[] obj = resultList.get(0);
        kixcCustomerDetailsRequestDto.setAccountNo((String) obj[0]);
```

You can use HQL except writing native queries(native queries may cause runtime exceptions) like this example and take the query result as a list of object arrays n set them into your POJO object.

PS:- if your query returns a single row you can use *query.getSingleResultList()* method to fetch the result